# ¿Como desplegar mensajes de un error 500 en CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Ya intenté con la directiva `init_set`, el archivo `index.php` esta establecido a `ENVIRONMENT=DEVELOPMENT`, he buscado mucho en la web y nada me ha funcionado.

Yo no tengo acceso a archivos de configuracion del servidor, es por ello que necesito activar los mensajes, pues hacer la depuracion esta complicada asi.

Solucion
 **Esta fue la modificacion que hice en el index.php**

```
define('ENVIRONMENT',   'development');
/**** ERROR REPORTING
Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.*/

switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
case 'development':  
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set('display_errors', 1 );
break;

case 'testing':
case 'production':
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    }
    else
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
    }
break;

default:
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
    exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
```

Comment: Para mostrar errores especificos, ya que en codeigniter solo mostrará 2 tipos: los 404 - No encontrado y los errores de DB puedes usar la función `show_error` para hacer debug de tu proyecto, info: [Error Handling](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Para las versiones viejas de CodeIgniter

El archivo `index.php` contiene un llamado a `ini_set('error_reporting', ..);`  , para cambiar el comportamiento con ese tipo de errores.

Así se ve el archivo por default:

```
/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| PHP ERROR REPORTING LEVEL
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CI runs with error reporting set to ALL.  For security
| reasons you are encouraged to change this when your site goes live.
| For more info visit:  http://www.php.net/error_reporting
|
*/
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Debajo de esa linea, añade `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` y los errores se mostrarán.

---

En la versión actual de CodeIgniter *(Enero de 2018)*.

El `index.php` cuenta con un switch y una variable para indicar el tipo de ambiente:

```
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;
    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    break;
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
```

Solo debes cambiar el valor en esta función:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

Es probable que los errores no se muestren por que el valor está puesto en `production` en lugar de `development`.